# SpriteKit Physics: Equal and opposite reaction

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm trying to animate a helicopter-thing in my game using a virtual joystick. The below code works well if your flying it actively, but now I want to animate the helicopter to a hover rotating it to the negative angle and apply a negative/positive vector to it to make it rapidly stop and "hover." And possibly bounce back and forth until its hovering. Any suggestions?

```
//Just move the hell with no physics
//[heli setPosition:CGPointMake(heli.position.x+self.joystick.x*2, heli.position.y+self.joystick.y*2)];

//Apply physics to the heli
float multiplier = 2.5;
[heli.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(_joystick.x*multiplier, _joystick.y*multiplier)];

//joystick x position is -99 to 99 
SKAction *rotation = [SKAction rotateToAngle:-1*(_joystick.x/2.0) duration:0];

[heli runAction: rotation];

//if i let go of the joystick it returns to zero - bounce to a hover
if (_joystick.x == 0) { //not working
    //check the current velocity?
    //[heli.physicsBody velocity];
    [heli.physicsBody applyForce:CGVectorMake(-1*(_joystick.x*multiplier*2), -1*(_joystick.y*multiplier*2))];
}
```

Comment: just give a try change  (_joystick.x == 0) to  (_joystick.x=< 0).you are checking negative vector with exact value i think it not possible inside a update loop

Comment: Make use of friction. That will cause the desired effect automatically.

Comment: @dragoneye I am. Why don't you think so?

Comment: @ZeMoon What exactly do you mean?

Comment: have a proper look at the friction property of SKPhysicsBody. It might help you in this direction.